# Does SSRS does support handling errors / exceptions?

Tags: reporting-services, reporting

I am trying to catch any error before the report is sent to subscribers.

If there is an error I would like to send a custom message like "server is in maintenance" or similar.

Microsoft Report Builder does not show any option to handle errors if SQL Server is down.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible within SSRS.

You could, if you like, have some routine which checks SQL Server is running.. But that is only one check. There are countless reasons why the report may not run.

I think you probably need to take a step back and look at what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Subscriptions are stored as jobs on your server. You can write a query to check the details of these jobs. If your SQL Server is down, then nothing will work. But you could have a subscription that regularly reports errors which would fire off once the server is back online. I know this is a high level explanation, but it should point you in the right direction. Here's an article that may help get you started:

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1846/how-to-easily-identify-a-scheduled-sql-server-reporting-services-report/